# What is the best way to combine a large number of small files to maximize recoverability

Tags: filesystems, compression, archive, diskimage

I have sets of large numbers of files (~5000 per directory) which are significantly slowing down my file system access. I have plenty of space, and the data is important. I'd like to combine them into a single file per directory. Creating an archive would be the simple solution, but I don't want to reduce the recoverability. Some sort of flat image (e.g., an uncompressed tar-file) would work fine, but I would think there's a format that could actually be more recoverable (e.g., by storing parity information) in the same amount of space. I'm working in an mixed unix/linux/mac environment.

Is there an image/compression format that minimizes compression while providing parity-type information, or would a raw image be the maximally recoverable file format?

Comment: What is "more recoverable"?  Why do you think "recoverability" will be reduced by a tar file?  How so?

Comment: By recoverability I mean the amount of original data that can be extracted from the data after a specific amount of damage (i.e., changed bits)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that tar would have _reduced_ recoverability -- as I understand it, it will be about the same as the original data. I'm wondering if there would be something _better_ than the original. For example, if you could compress the file to half the size, and then kept two copies of the file it would have the same disk-space "cost", but be more robust to data loss

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to solve your performance problem simply by creating a deeper tree of subdirectories with far fewer files in each directory.

Comment: true, but all of the files "belong" to each other -- there's no deeper logical subdivision possible. I could arbitrarily divide them up, but I'd rather tie them all together in a single file

Comment: The division does not have to be "logical".  Arbitrary is fine.  I've see lots applications that do that where there are many files, e.g. mail programs.